# Unable to deploy a DAG in Airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I am unable to deploy a DAG in airflow. Constantly giving the same error.
Running on 8080 port and scheduler is also on.

```
Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: bworkflow_dag.bworkflow_template 2020-08-11T00:00:00+00:00 [failed]> airflow-instance-test.c.cc-data-sandbox.internal
[2020-08-11 14:46:29,030] {__init__.py:50} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2020-08-11 14:46:29,031] {dagbag.py:396} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/kshitij/airflow/dags
/home/kshitij/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py:1342: PendingDeprecationWarning: The requested task could not be added to the DAG because a task with task_id create_tag_template_field_result is already in the DAG. Starting in Airflow 2.0, trying to overwrite a task will raise an exception.
  category=PendingDeprecationWarning)
Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: bworkflow_dag.bworkflow_template 2020-08-11T00:00:00+00:00 [failed]> airflow-instance-test.c.cc-data-sandbox.internal
```

I am using the correct path i.e. `~/airflow/dags`

Find the snippet of the code:

```
from builtins import range
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator import DataprocWorkflowTemplateInstantiateOperator

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='workflow_dag',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(days=1),
)

workflow_template = DataprocWorkflowTemplateInstantiateOperator(
    template_id="workflow_rds",
    project_id="<project name>",
    task_id="workflow_template",
    dag=dag)


workflow_template


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

It's a single task DAG.

Let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: those last 3 lines (from `workflow_template` task variable blank reference for no reason to `id __name__ == "__main__"` and `dag.cli()`) are unnecessary, remove them [particularly `dag.cli()`: i'm not sure what it does, but this could be causing problems]

Comment: Are you using Google Cloud Composer? If so, I would suggest tagging them and removing Cloud Dataproc.

Comment: @GaurangiSaxena I have hosted a VM on GCP and using airflow on port 8080

Comment: @y2k-shubham It worked..
Commented this `__name__ == "__main__" and dag.cli()`

Comment: @y2k-shubham Can you put it in the answer so that I can mark it as complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed over comments, following lines were not required and needed to be removed

```
...
workflow_template


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

taking them one-by-one

- `workflow_template`: this does nothing; just referencing a variable that holds a `task` (removing it is merely cleanup)
- `if __name__ == "__main__":`: intended to execute some piece of code only when file is [executed as a main program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419189/3679900). Not needed in a DAG file
- `dag.cli()`: this i believe was the cuprit. i haven't used this method before but the [docstring](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/b43f90abf4c7219d5d59cccb0514256bd3f2fdc7/airflow/models/dag.py#L1456) says it `Exposes a CLI specific to this DAG`, something that was creating problems for the process parsing dag-definition file (`webserver` actually)