# DAG cli and catchup

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have the DAG:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_bash_operator',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    tags=['example']
)
```

What is the significance of dag.cli()?
What role does cli() play?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

Today is 14th oct. When i add catchup false, it executes for 13 oct. Should not it just execute only for 14th. Without it executes for 12 and 13 which makes sense as it would backfill. But with catchup false why does it execute for 13th oct?

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_bash_operator',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    catchup=False,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    tags=['example']
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid setting the `start_date` to a relative value - this can lead to unexpected behaviour as this value is newly interpreted everytime the DAG file is parsed.

There is a long description within the [Airflow FAQ](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date):

> We recommend against using dynamic values as start_date, especially datetime.now() as it can be quite confusing. The task is triggered once the period closes, and in theory an @hourly DAG would never get to an hour after now as now() moves along.

Regarding `dag.cli()`, I would remove this whole part - it's definitely not required by DAG to be executed by airflow scheduler, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63360856/unable-to-deploy-a-dag-in-airflow).

Regarding `catchup=False`and why it executes for the 13th of October - Have a look on [scheduler documentation](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html)

> The scheduler won’t trigger your tasks until the period it covers has ended e.g., A job with schedule_interval set as @daily runs after the day has ended. This technique makes sure that whatever data is required for that period is fully available before the dag is executed. In the UI, it appears as if Airflow is running your tasks a day late

> **Note**
> If you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run with execution_date 2019-11-21 triggers soon after 2019-11-21T23:59.
> Let’s Repeat That, the scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

Also the article [Scheduling Tasks in Airflow](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/scheduling-tasks/) might be worth a read.

Comment: The execution date shown in Airflow is counter intuitive as it shows the date of the schedule for the instance it now executes after the interval is passed. Plus it shows UTC times. E.g. currently in Europe under CEST (Central European Summer Time) our execution "happens" at 22:00 instead of the scheduled 00:00.